# coffeescript, jade, stylus -> js, css asset manager? node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript

I work in coffeescript, jade and stylus.

My application serves two different "one page apps". For these apps I serve all asset in the initial payload.

I want to group, compile, and concatenate all coffeescript files and jade templeates into a single js asset and stylus files into a single css asset for each "one page app".

Then I can just leave my `/public/js` and `/public/css` alone and they will always have the current js and css asset files for the two different apps.

Has anyone setup a workflow like this before? Any ideas how I could do this?

Through research I found the process written about here but they don't say how they did it.
http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-trello-tech-stack/

Comment: Do you really need to submit the same question 3 times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with JS pretty simply with Express + [Stitch](https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch) / [StitchUp](https://github.com/timoxley/StitchUp)

Sample config:
https://gist.github.com/1094412

An alternative is also Interleave:

http://www.distractable.net/coding/javascript-builds-using-interleave

And the options for stylus middleware should sort you out for your CSS:
http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/docs/middleware.html

There's also a myriad of options over here:

http://toolbox.no.de/search?q=asset

Comment: @fancy Considering this is the only answer and it's pretty much the solution to your problem, why not mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a node app for this. It is V E R Y simple, but it works for me. The code is so simple (72 lines) you can adjust it anyway you like. Whenever you save a coffee, stylus or jade file it converts to js, css or html. It doesn't take care of file removals or any other fancy stuff. It's not perfect, but at least I know exactly how it works, which makes debugging easy.

https://github.com/Gijsjan/Template-Engine-Watcher

Comment: For the record: shortly after, I started using Grunt to manage this and many other tasks!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an open source project(MIT license) to address this problem:

[Giles - https://github.com/255BITS/giles](https://github.com/255BITS/giles)

Giles builds your static assets for you(Jade, Stylus, CoffeeScript).  It can be run standalone, as a web server, or as a connect module.  You can add support for other languages to Giles easily(see the github page)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [connect-assets](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets) pipeline to pull compiled Jade assets into your JavaScript by making them dependencies of the CoffeeScript files that use them.

I have a blog post with the details -> [Server side compiling of Jade templates with connect-assets](http://trevorpower.com/blog/server-side-compiling-of-jade-templates-with-connect-assets).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), with Grunt you can setup all kinds of workflows and tasks. I personally use [mean.io](https://github.com/linnovate/mean) as my boilerplate for most of my projects. They have a really nice Grunt file with most the tasks you need to concat and minify css and js into a single file using [assetmanager](https://github.com/ReedD/node-assetmanager). Mean.io doesn't use jade or stylus but you could easily add those Grunt tasks.